# Extracting a value in a header using post-http in a restful wabservice

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, post, http-headers

I'm a new rest programmer and I want to transmit the ip of the android device(Client) to the server and register it in a file. I want to use http request post for this and I have to transmit this parameter value in a header . I used

```
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var", "C02G8416DRJM"));
```

in my main activity so as to insert this information in the header of the request(I'm not sure if it's registred in the header or the body).

However, I couldn't retrieve this value in the sever part ... I tried this

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  String var= req.getParameter("var");
  Writer writer1 = null;
  try {
      writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\X\\Y\\Z\\header.txt"), "utf-8"));
   writer1.write(var);
  } catch (IOException ex){
    // report
  } finally {
     try {writer1.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you are using Servlet.doPost for receiving REST requests ?

JAX-RS makes it extremely simple. A resource can be defined as:

```
@Path("/fruit")
public class MyResource {

@GET
public String get() {
    System.out.println("GET");
    return Database.getAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{name}")
public String get(@PathParam("name")String payload) {
    System.out.println("GET");
    return Database.get(payload);
}

@POST
public void post(String payload) {
    System.out.println("POST");
    Database.add(payload);
}

@PUT
public void put(String payload) {
    System.out.println("PUT");
    Database.add(payload);
}
}
```

Complete sample at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-endpoint

Any parameters in the request can be retrieved as:

```
@Context Application app;
@Context UriInfo uri;
@Context HttpHeaders headers;
@Context Request request;
@Context SecurityContext security;
@Context Providers providers;
```

For example, all HTTP headers are available using `headers` field.

Complete sample showing this is at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs/request-binding

Comment: Thanks for your help but In this project, this information shouldn't be in the url ...that's why I'm trying to add this variable in a header . However, I didn't find any article about it . I'm not even sure if it's possible to add a variable in the header because some tutorial mention only how to extract static informations somehow such as host.... Still thinking about it